# Script doesn't work when executed with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sudo

Linux bash script:

```
function Print()
{
    echo $1
}

Print "OK"
```

This script runs successfully, when executed directly, and gives an error running with sudo:

```
alex@alex-linux:~/tmp$ ./sample-script 
OK
alex@alex-linux:~/tmp$ sudo ./sample-script 
[sudo] password for alex: 
./sample-script: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do you have

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line of the script? this may be needed

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps root has a different default shell that doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: This is likely the correct answer. If root's shell is say, dash, the `function` keyword would be invalid. That would be true for any other POSIX shell. The fact that the bash shebang worked is a strong indicator that this is exactly the problem.